# Access iPod music folder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible on the iPhone to access ipod folder in order to play in my app music that user chooses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use the MPMediaLibrary and MPMediaPickerController to get this functionality.

If you look on the Apple iPhone Dev Center, you should be able to find the AddMusic example code to see how this works.

Also there is plenty more information in the MediaPlayer.framework documentation in Xcode.

Comment: This is only in OS 3.0 and onwards.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You didn't specify that you needed this to work on anything less than 3.0 - so I assumed.
Without the 3.0 software, there is no official API to access the iPod Library.