# iOS iTunes Integration

Tags: iphone, itunes

Can I access the iTunes library of the iPhone inside my app?
if so, are there any good tutorials or documentation on the subject?

Comment: Removed the continouos-integration tag because that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625625/access-to-iphone-music-library , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199382/access-ipod-music-folder

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the iPod then you can look at MPMusicPlayerController class or 
MPMediaQuery class for querying the iTunes library.

You'll find full documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MediaPlayer framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html) to access the iPod library on the device.
You can use the MPMediaPickerController and other related classed to to choose songs or playlists to play in your app, but beyond that you can't do much else.

You can also create queries to select specific types of media.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the iPod library audio files.

You can however look up useless metadata, or ask the iPod software to play a tune on your behalf.

It's quite crippled.